# when importing images dynamically in flash how can i fix all images size fixed?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, flash-cc

when i work with flash i getting trouble when working with images
now my present project i'm uploading images dynamically, but here main problem is all the images sizes are different when i put the images into flash canvas every image looking different size means exact image size, but i need all the images should look same size in the canvas

check the image
if i change both of the height and width values that is not effecting any where, that is automatically taking fixed images size but i need all the images looks exact size, i didn't get any thing

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xod.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I have the solution to your problem.

Basically, you need to create a container (if you haven't already done so) to 'hold' the images as they come up OR know the maximum height and width you want for the images. Then you need to make sure the aspect ratio is correct (so your picture won't be skewed. )

Code Example:

```
    var wHRatio:Number=image.width/image.height; //this will give you the width to height ratio to make sure aspect ratio stays the same.

    if (image.width>mcContainer.width){ //if not using container, enter max width
      image.width=mcContainer.width;
      image.height=image.width/wHRatio; 
      // at this point, if the height is still taller than the container, you want to shrink the image again so it's no taller than the container.
      if (image.height>mcContainer.height){ //if not using container, enter max height
        image.height=mcContainer.height;
        image.width=image.height*wHRatio;
      }
    }
```

**** Don't forget to 'addChild' after you've completed the re-sizing.

This may not be the most efficient way of doing things, but I think it will work for your purposes.